# How do i call methods from different objects in an arrayList?

Tags: compiler-errors, processing

I'm creating a simple game for my coursework. I have an array list containing different types of enemies made from different classes I have created. All the objects have a method called `drawEnemy` which draws the object to the screen (so the function `drawEnemy()` is in every class). I am trying to draw all the objects in the array in the draw loop.

```
ArrayList<Object> enemies;

enemies.add(new enemy1())
enemies.add(new enemy2())
enemies.add(new enemy3())

void draw(){
    for(Object i : enemies)
      i.drawEnemy();
}
```

This tells me that the function `drawEnemy` does not exist.

Comment: Remember, generics is for when you _don't_ want just Object. Everything is, by definition, an extension of `Object`. You want an `ArrayList<Enemy>`, and then iterate using `for(Enemy e: enemeies)`. Now you can call any method you defined in your Enemy class, because the compiled _knows_ those methods exist. But don't give Enemy a method `drawEnemy`, just call it `draw`: we already know it draws an enemy, adding an echo just adds an echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `enemies` as an `ArrayList<Object>`, meaning that iterating over it will return `Object` references (regardless of the actual runtime types).

If you want to iterate over a list of enemies like this, you should extract a common interface or base class for all the enemy classes, and use it for the list type:

```java
public interface Enemy {
    void drawEnemy();
}

public class Enemy1 implements Enemy {
    // code...
}

public class Enemy2 implements Enemy {
    // code...
}

public class Enemy3 implements Enemy {
    // code...
}

ArrayList<Enemy> enemies;
// list is then initialized and populated as it was

void draw() {
    for (Enemy i : enemies) // Note the i is defined as an Enemy
      i.drawEnemy();
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is the enemies are of different object types. I have used different classes to create different types of enemies, so enemy1 will be one class and enemy2 will be another.

Comment: @Tahseen arg, missed that in the original question, mea culpa. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks man been trying to figure this out all day. Would this work if I used extends instead of implements? what is the difference between the two?